# jquery select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Facing some problems with jQuery selectors.

My HTML is like:

```
<form method="" action="">  
    <p id="question_1">  
        <h1 id="question">1. A Question</h1>  
        <div id="choices">  
            <p id="option1"><input type="radio" id="option" name="q_1" value="1" />A</p>  
            <p id="option2"><input type="radio" id="option" name="q_2" value="2" />B</p>  
            <p id="option3"><input type="radio" id="option" name="q_3" value="3" />C</p>              
        </div>  
    </p>      
.  
.  
.  
</form>
```

There are n such questions.

I want to highlight the <p> containing the 3rd radio button for each question. For example,

```
    p#question_1 > p#option3  
    p#question_2 > p#option3  
    p#question_3 > p#option3
```

How to do that?

I was trying something like this, without any success:

```
$("form p#question_" + i).filter("p:eq(3)").addClass("correct");
```

Comment: It seems likely that you have duplicated IDs within your markup, which is *invalid* according to the specification.

Comment: Try using 'code sample' button in edit mode (the one with zeroes and ones). It's much easier than '&lt;' and '&gt;'

Comment: @karim79 - More than just likely, the `radio` elements all have the ID `option`. I agree that others (like `choices`) are likely as well.

Comment: IDs should be unique in an html document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to highlight the `<p>` containing
>   the 3rd radio button for each
>   question.

Use start with `^` selector with `nth-child` like this:

```
$('p[id^="question"]:nth-child(3)').addClass('correct');
```

What `^="question"` does is that it selects all paragraphs starting with `question` text in their ids and then `nth-child(3)` is used to select the third paragraph.

**More Info:**

- [Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- [:nth-child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

If your third answer is always correct, you might opt for something like this instead:

```
<p class="first">Blah blah</p>
<p class="second">Blah blah</p>
<p class="third">Blah blah</p>
```

Then simply:

```
$("p.third").addClass("correct");
```

That should hopefully tempt you to get rid of those dupe IDs.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want this to work if you have many div's with answers in them?  Decorate each such div with DivChoices, and then:

```
$(".DivChoices").each(function (index, item) { $("p", item).last().addClass('correct'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing that, here is a nice jQuery selectors refcard that will be very useful for you in the future.

http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/jquery-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to just add a class to the third option for each question?